# Is there a way to use Simple_format and truncate together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My best guess is that I need to write a new method that does simple_format and truncate, but I'm not really sure how to do that, or if it's necessary.

Here is an example of how I'm trying to use it now:

```
<%= simple_format truncate(recap.body, length: 500, separator: ' ') { link_to '(read more)', recap} %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<%= simple_format truncate((h(recap.body) + link_to("read more", recap_path(recap))), length: 500, separator: ' ') %>
```

it should work for your scenario